# Can I Use a Custom Data Layer Name in GTM?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am coming from Adobe world here - do I need to call my data layer "dataLayer" in GTM? Or can I define my own? And if so, where - in the GTM snippet?

Answer (score 2):

You can!  Yes, in the snippet.  [Google mentions this in their documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#renaming).

From Google's example:

```js
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','myNewName','GTM-XXXX');</script>
```

All you have to do is change `myNewName` near the end to whatever you want.

Make sure you do NOT change the occurrence of `dataLayer` right in the middle of the snippet.  This is part of the snippet's logic to see if you are using a different name for the data layer.  If the name you chose does not equal `dataLayer`, it adds a query parameter to the URL of the `gtm.js` script, to tell it what name to use.  Otherwise it defaults to `dataLayer`.

Comment: I see that now - thanks!